# Unable to use org.joda time in clojure

Tags: ide, clojure

In Java i have this line

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

which in clojure i am trying to convert into clojure code and i have imported the file itself 
but this line does not seem to work

```
(def fmt (.forPattern DateTimeFormat ("yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss")))
```

giving the exception of CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: DateTimeFormat in this context, compiling:(ShipDataRecord.clj:65)

Or am i doing it wrongly could someone kindly explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, static methods in clojure are called like this:

```
(DateTimeFormat/forPattern args...)
```

Second, you should not surround method/function arguments with parentheses, i.e. this is incorrect (disregarding for now invalid syntax for calling static methods):

```
(.forPattern DateTimeFormat ("yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Parentheses around `"yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss"` should be left out.

So, the valid way to do what you want is:

```
(def fmt (DateTimeFormat/forPattern "yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 4):

alternatively, you could use [clj-time](https://github.com/seancorfield/clj-time)

Answer (score 1):

As you are already familiar with Joda-Time, you can use [Clojure.Joda-Time](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.joda-time).